# Working with Sql Developer unable to update table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Question..
create an
SQL update statement which doubles the P_DISCOUNT for all products provided by vendors in TN or
FL
I have 2 tables and i'm trying to reference the vendor table which contains the states and the p_discount is located in the product table.

```
update PRODUCT
set P_DISCOUNT = 2 * P_DISCOUNT
where VENDOR.V_STATE in 
  (select VENDOR.V_STATE from VENDOR where  VENDOR.V_STATE = ('FL','TN'))
```

any suggestions would be great

Thank you,

Comment: You should really decide if you are using SQL Server or Oracle.  These are very different databases.

Comment: What is the relationship between `PRODUCT` and `VENDOR`? What column joins these tables?

Comment: PRODUCT and VENDOR are linked with V_CODE..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
update PRODUCT
set P_DISCOUNT = 2 * P_DISCOUNT
where V_CODE in 
    (select VENDOR.V_CODE from VENDOR where VENDOR.V_STATE IN ('FL','TN'))
```

You are filtering the condition based on joining field, not on any field in one of the tables

Comment: Error starting at line : 154 in command -
update PRODUCT
set P_DISCOUNT = 2 * P_DISCOUNT
where V_CODE in 
  (select VENDOR.V_CODE from VENDOR where  VENDOR.V_STATE = ('FL','TN'))
Error at Command Line : 157 Column : 59
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL
01797. 00000 -  "this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I updated the answer. It is `IN` operator that needs to be used

Answer (score -1):

> update    PRODUCT  set   P_DISCOUNT = 2 * P_DISCOUNT  where  V_STATE in
>     (select  VENDOR.V_STATE from VENDOR where  VENDOR.V_STATE in ('FL','TN'))

Comment: get that error with thatError starting at line : 154 in command -
update PRODUCT
set P_DISCOUNT = 2 * P_DISCOUNT
where VENDOR.V_STATE in 
  (select VENDOR.V_STATE from VENDOR where  VENDOR.V_STATE in ('FL','TN'))
Error at Command Line : 156 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "VENDOR"."V_STATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Please explain how this "answer" improves on OP's query as stated in the question.

Comment: Does the table Product has the column V_STATE?

Comment: @user3572912 - it appears that you simply copied OP's query and posted it as an "answer". Please explain how this answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis: please check the query carefully,then you can see the changed part.

Comment: If Product table has the column V_state the below query will work.                                                                                                            update PRODUCT set P_DISCOUNT = 2 * P_DISCOUNT where V_STATE in
(select VENDOR.V_STATE from VENDOR where VENDOR.V_STATE in ('FL','TN'))

Comment: Yes, I see now what you did. However, in my opinion this is not an answer. You need to explain the answer, not just post a query and expect people to figure out what you did.

Comment: If V_state is the column of the table Product then the update query will work 100 %.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71441/discussion-between-user3572912-and-bob-jarvis).